# How to wrap an image in a div, and then center the div

Tags: html, css

I have got this css:

```
   <style type="text/css">

    #heading{
        margin:auto; 
        background-color: brown;

    }
</style>
```

and this html:

```
<div id="heading">
        <image src="image_files/header-background.jpg" alt="speakom"   />
    </div>
```

I dont know the exact size of the image.. But I want the div to wrap the image with the exact width and then I want to center that div..how do I acheive that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `inline-block` will make the div the width of whatever it's contents are, and allow you to center it with auto margins:

```
#heading {
    margin: 0px auto;
    display: inline-block;
}​
```

Comment: A quick note... this should work, however there are situations where an extra div wrapping everything up would be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Write like this:

```
.parent{
  text-align:center;
}

    #heading{
     display:inline-block;
     *display:inline;/* For IE7*/
     *zoom:1/* For IE7*/
     text-align:left;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
 <div id="heading">
        <img src="image_files/header-background.jpg" alt="speakom"   />
 </div>
</div>
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/sAYEq/

Comment: you can center an inline element with text align:center; to it's parent. That's effect you can get same effect with inline-block. May be you can call it's a Hack.

Answer (score 0):

to get your

```
margin: auto;
```

declaration to work like you want, you need to specify a width for the div. Without knowing the size of the image, you'll just need to guess what it is or use javascript

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the answer by Dave does not (no longer? not always?) work. My preferred solution uses flexbox:

```html
<article>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/300/200" />
    <figcaption>Cute!</figcaption>
  </figure>
</article>
```

```css
article {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
figure {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
figcaption {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

See it for yourself at https://codepen.io/marcvangend/pen/vPBVOv.

Advantages:

- The centered element (here: `<figure>`) wraps tightly around the image.
- All elements inside (here: `<img>`, `<figcaption>`) get the same width.
- Because we're not using `text-align: center`, the text in the figcaption remains left-aligned.